# Weather APIs For Android

Tags: android, weather

I would like to know of some API which i could use to retrieve weather information in Android. I came across samples which make use of the Google Weather API and it works fine.But since the Google Weather API is not official and open for public yet , there is the risk of it being discontinued anytime.

Also some blogs say that the data returned by the Google Weather API is not accurate and caution using it.

Hence i am looking for some API which i can use in Android.If anyone is already using some API kindly let me know.

Comment: http://worldweatheronline.com

Answer (score 14):

I made a wrapper for Yahoo Weather API on android.
Check it here: 
https://github.com/zh-wang/YWeatherGetter4a

Comment: Hola. I used that library in my app. Unfortunately when I want to retrieve my current location city name it just shows country location: Iran. I even used exact latitude and longitude, again just country name. How can I increase the precision?

Comment: I've used your wrapper, and it was working great (thanx btw!), but stopped all of the sudden... I was using the weather from gps... Just gives me an error that the location can't be found. Even your sample app doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: Does not work, because API not more available as public.

Comment: Yahoo's reverse geocoding is not free now, but weather api still works. I have changed reverse geocoding from Yahoo's api to android's geocoder.

Answer (score 4):

yes u can use yahoo weather api

http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/ check this one it provides api for having weather inforamation for any city

http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2502265 as below link will give u weather information for Sunnyvale which have WOEID=2502265 which is defined at above link after w..

and for different woied id for different city u can use this api
[http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=ahmedabad=[yourappidhere]](http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=ahmedabad=%5Byourappidhere%5D)

put ur city name after "q" at this link

i hope this will solve ur issue

Comment: i want to get json response from this.. how can i do that ??

Comment: this is not for commercial use

Answer (score 0):

FeedSyndicate offers one that we've used.  It isn't free but I wouldn't build any commercial application on a service that I could not get support from.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo has a good API http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

It's free and xml!!!
Java has good XML-capabilities, so it's an option.

Hope I can help you.

Comment: It is free for personal use. Not if you are a company.

Answer (score 0):

World Weather Online has a free weather API. It's available for non-commercial and commercial use. You can find it at http://www.worldweatheronline.com/free-weather-feed.aspx.

The Weather Channel also has a great API. Not sure if it's commercial or not though. I would think not. You can access it at http://www.weather.com/services/xmloap.html

Answer (score 0):

Aeris Weather API has a full Android SDK:

https://www.aerisweather.com/support/docs/toolkits/aeris-android-sdk/

Shameless plug,

We offer a free development account that just limits hits, as your app grows, so do the plans.

I work with AerisWeather but really enjoy our APIs. We work hard to make them user friendly and to get you the content you need without having to spend too much time integrating everything.

Comment: Continuing with the shameless plugs, we just released an update to the Aeris Android Weather SDK with additional endpoints, etc.. :-)

Comment: This link is now broken, as the company sold to someone else

Comment: Updated @MarcStevenPlotz, didn't realize that link was broken, thanks.