# Weather databases

Tags: android, weather

So I am trying to develop a app that lets you see the current weather like
accuweather etc...

but I can't find a database to get the current weather data

So please if anybody of you knows wheere to get them answer

Comment: you have try google weather API's?

Comment: Try searching 'weather api' instead of 'weather database'. In addition to Google and Yahoo, there's also Weather Underground: http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weather APIs For Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307831/weather-apis-for-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the yahoo api

```
http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=1940631&u=c
```

that give the weather and u want to parse it

Answer (score 0):

I have used the iGoogle one. You will need to implement an XML parser.
I use it as follows in a Java program:

```
URL googleweatherapi = new URL("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=$" + city);
```

It's normally good at getting the correct location... %20 for spaces in city variable;

```
String city = "New%20York";
```

Comment: Probably best to encode it using [URLEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html). In this case it would be `URLEncoder.encode("New York", "utf-8");`